# Missing few pixels css height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create spans with `display:inline-block`,`height:50px` and `margin 25px` top and bottom. The wrapper div has a height of 100px and has `overflow: auto` property.

Even though height of span + margin-top + margin-bottom = height of wrapper div, the vertical scroll appears.

I know that giving min-height will solve the problem but I was curious to know where I'm losing a few pixels in the whole process.

Please see the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tejas_spy007/sz3rdhpg/) or the demo below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#myToolbar {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.toolbar-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 25px 2.5%;
  background-color: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="myToolbar">
  <span class="toolbar-item"></span><span class="toolbar-item"></span><span class="toolbar-item"></span><span class="toolbar-item"></span><span class="toolbar-item"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `inline-block` elements are affected by `line-height`. Have you tried [making the objects display type `block` and making them `float` left instead](http://jsfiddle.net/sz3rdhpg/1/)?

Comment: in your #myToolbar class add   overflow: hidden;

Comment: @Marty making them float ignores white-space: no-wrap. Anyways thanks for the suggestion. Issue got fixed with adding vertical-align: top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, inline and inline-block elements are set with `vertical-align: baseline`.

Change the `vertical-align` value to either top / middle / bottom and there will be no more funny behaviour.

[From the MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Values_(for_inline_elements))

> baseline
>
> Aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of its parent. The baseline of some replaced elements, like `<textarea>` is not specified by the HTML specification, meaning that their behavior with this keyword may change from one browser to the other.

CSS / HTML / Demo

Using `vertical-align: top`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#myToolbar {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.toolbar-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 25px 2.5%;
  background-color: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="myToolbar">
  <span class="toolbar-item"></span><span class="toolbar-item"></span><span class="toolbar-item"></span><span class="toolbar-item"></span><span class="toolbar-item"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: No worries. The default baseline value is the cause of a lot of confusion with inline elements!